# Resize image by adding extra black pixels at borders

Tags: c++, image-processing, ffmpeg, bitblt

I would like to resize an image(lower resolution to higher resolution) by adding black pixels at the borders. I have raw image data available in YUV420/RGB format. I want to add back pixels to this raw image data and change its resolution to desired state. Example [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyEcI.jpg) to [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTrWL.jpg). I have all my code in CPP, and i am also using ffmpeg libraries to scale/convert data format.

Comment: See [pad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) and `doc/examples/filtering_video.c`.

Comment: @llogan thank you for the comment, this is what i was looking for. I have tried the same and was able to add padding to an image in commandline. Can you please point me how to achieve the same using ffmpeg library functions (taking raw image data as input) in cpp code.